# .ics Calendar File - Parsing Date Time - What is the time format?

Tags: php, regex, datetime, calendar

I am coding in php, attempting to get the start\end dates and times for events. I am utilizing the following RegEx for parsing out the information:

```
$pattern='/(?P<StartDate>[0-9]{8})T(?P<StartTime>[0-9]{6})
.+(?P<EndDate>[0-9]{8})T(?P<EndTime>[0-9]{6})/';
```

The sample event entry is here:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:34b09fd7-8e6e-4d56-86b0-445745b89d93
ORGANIZER;CN=*********:mailto:*********
DTSTART;TZID="(GMT-06.00) Central Time (US & Canada)":20100413T130000
DTEND;TZID="(GMT-06.00) Central Time (US & Canada)":20100413T160000
STATUS:CONFIRMED
CLASS:PRIVATE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY
TRANSP:OPAQUE
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:TRUE
DTSTAMP:20100414T140711Z
SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT
```

20100413T130000 and 20100413T160000 are the start and end points.

The dates are straight forward, however how do I interpret the time part?

This event starts at one and ends at four.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Are the times of the events changing and you want to find a way of determining what the times are?
*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are in HHmmss format where HH is the hours in a 24 hour format. `130000` is 13:00:00, ie. 1 pm (13 - 12 = 1 pm), 0 minutes, 0 seconds.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't see that after staring it. Thank you.